# How do I avoid passing the same prop to every component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React project.

In the following code, you can see that I am passing the same prop (`theme`: boolean value representing whether the app is currently toggled to dark mode or light mode) to every component. The reason I am passing `theme` to every component is because I use it to determine which mode I should style each component (using styled-components) in. This action of passing the same prop to every component seems redundant. How do I avoid the redundancy?

```js
const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = persist('theme', true);

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <div className='app'>
        <Toggle theme={theme} setTheme={setTheme} />
        <About theme={theme} />
        <Links theme={theme} />
        <Footer theme={theme} />
        <Background theme={theme} />
      </div>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};
```

Here is the code for the `persist` hook if it useful:

```js
import React from 'react';

const persist = (key, defaultValue) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => {
    const persistentState = localStorage.getItem(key);

    return persistentState ? JSON.parse(persistentState) : defaultValue;
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state));
  }, [state, key]);
  return [state, setState];
};

export default persist;
```

Comment: State can live on the component as you are doing, or can be on a store and reused through the whole app. This is a perfect example of why state managements tools such as Redux and Context are needed when scaling bigger apps - I would suggest you looking into some context tutorial to see how that works

Comment: This is perfect for your use case, I'd suggest following the entire tutorial for implementing what you are trying to achieve: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/introduction-react-context-api/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**React Context** will come handy in here. You can create a **ThemeProvider** like so :-

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  isDark: false,
  setIsDark:()=>void
});

const ThemeProvider = ({
  children,
}) => {
   const [isDark, setIsDark] = usePersistentState('theme', true); // default: dark mode

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{
    isDark,
    setIsDark,
  }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ThemeProvider;
```

Then you can wrap your respectable root `App` component or whatever you have inside this `ThemeProvider` like so :-

```
<ThemeProvider>
<App/>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Now in say, `Links` you can use the context this way :-

```
const {isDark,setIsDark} = useContext(ThemeContext);
```

I implemented something similar some time back for one of my app. You can take a reference from [here](https://github.com/lapstjup/animeccha/blob/main/src/components/ColorModeContext/ColorModeContext.tsx) (Ignore the TypeScript bit) -